# jQueryUI Scroll Issue with IFrame

Tags: jquery-ui, iframe, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

There is already a similar question asked but there is no response([Draggable JQuery UI scroll issue when using within iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21010675/draggable-jquery-ui-scroll-issue-when-using-within-iframe)).

I want scroll to work for the draggable object in IFrame. Please suggest.

Here is the jsFiddle - http://fiddle.jshell.net/Msd7v/29/

Comment: can you console out the offset in your fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this http://fiddle.jshell.net/vryz2t1o/1/, I managed to make it work when you are scrolling down. You need to try to figure out scrolling up and you are done.

Comment: Thanks Buddy. I will look into the code and post the comment for the code that I will finalize to solve the issue.

Comment: Hey guys any update on this one? the code only works if you set your iframe height in less than 850px